# Basic kernel test fails with Type of Drupal\KernelTests\Core\Entity\EntityKernelTestBase::$modules must be array

Tags: testing, 9

Trying to port a Drupal 7 module to 9 with accompanying test and getting this error immediately when running it:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Type of Drupal\KernelTests\Core\Entity\EntityKernelTestBase::$modules must be array (as in class Drupal\KernelTests\KernelTestBase) in /var/www/html/docroot/core/tests/Drupal/KernelTests/Core/Entity/EntityKernelTestBase.php on line 12
```

The test:

```
class MyModuleTest extends EntityKernelTestBase {

  use NodeCreationTrait;

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\mymodule\Query\YearsQuery
   */
  protected $query;

  /**
   * @var array $modules
   */
  protected static $modules = [
    'node',
    'mymodule',
    'mymodule_test',
  ];

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function setUp() : void {
    parent::setUp();
    ...
```

I checked around some of the core classes - the $modules declaration looks the same. Note that I am using PHPUnit 9.

Comment: It's probably the access modifier - all core tests use `public` rather than `protected`

Comment: I get it with either one. I saw core tests use protected as well, for example `MessageEntityTest`.

Comment: Oh yeah I see it, interestingly none of those declare the `array` type. Does `public static $modules` work? The class you're inheriting from declares `$modules` as `public`, maybe the trouble is being caused by the change to the visibility and/or type

Comment: Yep, tried all those combinations.

Comment: EntityKernelTestBase in Drupal 9.1.4 declares $modules as protected static, not public? Are we looking at the same class?

Comment: My bad, had an old codebase open. Have you definitely tried without the type declaration (`array`)? That's literally the only difference between your code and core's

Comment: if I remove the entire statement I still get the error. Even if I switch to KernelTestBase and copy in its declaration I get the same error. It's almost like this isn't the actual error.

Comment: Ah ok so the problem's elsewhere - are you on PHP8?

Comment: PHP 7.4.x. PHPUnit 9.

Comment: @Clive, please don't suggest using `public`! It's always been `protected`, but cleaning up core has proven difficult. While D8 still has some remnants of this wrong usage, D9 is finally fixed with no remaining uses of `public`. It would be nice to keep it that way!

Comment: Ok well that aside, how do I figure out what is wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the `on line 12` part of the error - that doesn't seem to correspond to any code that could be generating that error.

Comment: @anonymous I was looking at the wrong codebase (D8), where it's `public` - I definitely wasn't suggesting it _should_ be public, they were just debug suggestions to see if the modifier was causing it :) But as you obviously feel strongly about it I'll take that on board, cheers for the tip!

Comment: Looks like its refusing to run until 'array' is added to either EntityKernelTestBase or KernelTestBase for the $modules variable. WEIRD. This has to be in PHP or PHPUnit 9.

Comment: Trying to work this through...I think the original error would make sense for the original code you had. `protected static array $modules` would have caused it because property types are still invariant in PHP7.4, and the parent classes don't declare a type for `$modules`. So if you've changed that loads of times to test, is there any chance those changes haven't made their way to the server? Bad VM sync or something maybe?

Comment: Do you have strict type checking declared in your test file?

Comment: No I removed the declare statement. I have restarted the VM a few times. PHPStorm is also underlining the core tests with error squiggles too indicating that they need the type declaration.

Comment: That's odd too - that fatal error is literally switched on by adding `declare(strict_types=1);`, it's off otherwise, and it's a per-file declaration. The phpstorm thing is normal since a recent update (I get it on all un-typed properties in any project)

Comment: Yes I am utterly baffled and its blocking me from porting some modules for a client project. I can run custom kernel tests on Drupal 8 projects in PHPUnit 8, which makes me think its a compatibility issue with PHPUnit 9.

Comment: Baffling is right. I just don't see how it can be a compatibility issue - the error is caused by `strict_types` being on, and it's impossible to set it globally (https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints_v5#strict_types_declare_directive). So if it's not in the file, as the first line or you'd get a compile error, it doesn't make sense. Unless the `declare` statement somehow found its way into one/more of the parent class files during debugging?

Comment: No, I did not modify those files other than try adding array to the $modules declaration as advised by PHPStorm.

Answer (score 0):

From [KernelTestBase](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21tests%21Drupal%21KernelTests%21KernelTestBase.php/class/KernelTestBase/9.2.x):

```
 /**
  * Modules to enable.
  *
  * The test runner will merge the $modules lists from this class, the class
  * it extends, and so on up the class hierarchy. It is not necessary to
  * include modules in your list that a parent class has already declared.
  *
  * @see \Drupal\Tests\KernelTestBase::enableModules()
  * @see \Drupal\Tests\KernelTestBase::bootKernel()
  *
  * @var array
  */
 protected static $modules = [];
```

You'll need to match this declaration in your own code (though you can add to the array).

Comment: That is what I have, and is not working. It errors immediately.

Comment: That error cannot match the code you've shown, as the error says modules is not an array, and you have defined it as an array. This means your problem lies elsewhere, such as debugging the wrong file, debugging the right file but on the wrong environment, having something clogged in a cache somewhere etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my problem stemmed entirely from using the wrong KernelTestBase include. My IDE suggested KernelTestBase as I was typing, and I did not look at the path:

```
use Drupal\Tests\token\Kernel\KernelTestBase;
```

vs

```
use Drupal\KernelTests\KernelTestBase;
```

send coffee.